# Why does comb behave differently inside the loop?

Tags: raku

Note: I'm doing this all from the REPL using 
    This is Rakudo Star version 2019.03.1 built on MoarVM version 2019.03
implementing Perl 6.d.

From euler project #22 there is a names.txt file similar to 
"JERE","HAI","ELDEN","DORSEY","DARELL","BRODERICK","ALONSO", ...

When I read that in, split and sort it I get the list of names as I'd expect.

```
for '../names.txt'.IO.slurp.split(',').sort -> $name {
    say $name;
}
```

That prints out

```
...
"ZONIA"
"ZORA"
"ZORAIDA"
"ZULA"
"ZULEMA"
"ZULMA"
```

Now if I add `comb()`

```
for '../names.txt'.IO.slurp.split(',').sort -> $name {
    say $name.comb;
}
```

I'm getting

```
...
(" Z O N I A ")
(" Z O R A ")
(" Z O R A I D A ")
(" Z U L A ")
(" Z U L E M A ")
(" Z U L M A ")
```

However, if I just run from the repl;

```
> "ZULMA".comb
```

I get

(Z U L M A)  # Note the lack of quotes

Why is `comb` behaving differently in these two scenarios?

Comment: In the REPL (acknowledging @Holli's example): `> "ZULMA".raku.comb` returns 
`(" Z U L M A ")` .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not behaving differently. In one case the quotes are a syntax element - part of the code - and in the other case data read verbatim from the file:

```
"ZULMA".comb
'"ZULMA"'.comb
```

The data is different. not the behaviour.

Comment: Seems so obvious all of the sudden. Thanks.

Comment: @jmcneirney My genes must defy loose ends; did you forget to click the accept button (check mark) for this answer?